# Inspect Element can change anything, and its ok?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I found it handy to style my webpages with google chrome by changing css values via 'inspect element'.

A lot of you may already know this but I just recently found out that I can also edit the whole entire html e.g.(change `div` tags to `a` tags, add inline javascript, change form values, etc.)

I made a simple test:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select'])) echo $_POST['select'];
?>

<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="selecttest.php" method="post">
<select name="select">
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I click submit it echos `100`. I changed the value to `something` via google chrome `inspect element` clicked submit and it echos `something`. I tried putting `<a href="http://www.google.com">100</a>` as the value. When I clicked on submit it echos a hyperlink `100`

Isn't this feature dangerous? I can't imagine anything extremely dangerous right now because I'm still new to programming but I'm just thinking what real black hat hackers with years of experience can do with that much freedom. Right now I'm just thinking 'Just filter out ALL user input and your safe'.

So my question is, is there any real actual threat from this feature even if you filter out ALL user input?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't worry too much over DevTools, since any change there is local to the user's browser.  You should instead worry about any incoming network data, such as the contents of a GET or POST request.

As a programmer you should always validate the input you get from a browser, making sure it's within your expected range of values.

Comment: Absolutely, since the same input can be easily emulated using `curl` or another utility, and poor input checking is probably the most common attack surface.

Comment: But will there be a possible threat even if I do check user input? Lets say I have 100% checked and sanitize user input, can they still hurt my site through the devtools? I just want to know so that I am aware of the possible threat.

Comment: @joespina: not greater than the Chrome browser, in any case... I suggest some reading on the [web application security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security). DevTools is not THE thing that you should be worried about.